# Spring security kerberos size of a request header field exceeds server limit error

Tags: java, spring, apache, spring-security, kerberos

We encountered problem with windows auth login application.[Spring security kerberos windows authentication](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-kerberos/tree/master/spring-security-kerberos-samples/sec-server-win-auth/src/main)  used for this login process.
Then spring security win-auth implemented to our project .
It's works on some customers .But some customers encountered an error like below.

```
Bad Request
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Size of a request header field exceeds server limit.
```

So there was a [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/362280/apache-bad-request-size-of-a-request-header-field-exceeds-server-limit-with-ke) in serverfault.We changed **LimitRequestFieldSize** of  apache . But it didn't solve our case.My question is  not directly related with apache.So I want to ask my question in here.

Problem is related with size.This size depends user's Active directory groups.
Some groups contains other groups probably.

How can I reduce this size without changing Active Directory ? There are too much customer,we can't change groups of all users.

**Second point :**

Our configuration file is like this

```
server:
    port: 8080
app:
    ad-domain: EXAMPLE.ORG
    ad-server: ldap://WIN-EKBO0EQ7TS7.example.org/
    service-principal: HTTP/neo.example.org@EXAMPLE.ORG
    keytab-location: /tmp/tomcat.keytab
    ldap-search-base: dc=example,dc=org
    ldap-search-filter: "(| (userPrincipalName={0}) (sAMAccountName={0}))"
```

We're using search filter

```
"(| (userPrincipalName={0}) (sAMAccountName={0}))"
```

but there is no group filter in the sample code.

I want to solve this issue on the source code , if it's possible.

Is there any way to limit groups of user with spring security ?

Or any other idea ?

Regards

Comment: What operating system (exact version) are you running Apache on?  How many groups is a problematic user actually in?

Comment: One of the problematic user has 25 groups. And another one has 13 groups.This groups can member of another groups.
I can successfully login to app .I have 34 groups in AD .I'm using ldap browser plugin on eclipse IDE for check groups.
This plugin only shows direct groups. So I can't check nested groups with this plugin. Operating system is Redhat .

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your question and what you wrote, shows me that you took very little effort to solve the problem on your own. You are mixing a lot of stuff, let me sort it out:

1. Your Spring Webapp runs likely on Tomcat: this will not send you 400 with that text
2. You do use Spring Sec Kerberos, which is crap btw: this will not send you 400
3. Someone intermediate system tells you that the header size is too large due to the PAC data: yay

Likely your customer's reverse proxy (Apache Web Server?) refuses to forward the `Authorize` header back to the Tomcat. You haven't provided the size you have set for `LimitRequestFieldSize`. At worst, you have to set the [max possible token size on Windows](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2012/09/12/maxtokensize-and-windows-8-and-windows-server-2012/) and add the overhead for Base64. Enable [request header logging](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html), take the Base 64 token and pass it to an [ASN.1 decoder](https://lapo.it/asn1js/). If it fails, the token is incomplete, increase limit.

Our setting is `./extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:    LimitRequestFieldSize 32768` and we have a lot of groups, hundreds upto.